# Count seen users per week

Tags: mysql, sql, count

My input table looks like:

| id | user_id | at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-12-07 13:07:35 |
| 2 | 794 | 2020-12-07 13:12:17 |
| 3 | 794 | 2020-12-07 13:12:26 |
| 4 | 794 | 2020-12-07 13:12:27 |
| 5 | 263 | 2020-12-07 13:12:50 |
| 6 | 263 | 2020-12-07 13:12:50 |
| 7 | 263 | 2020-12-07 13:13:10 |
| 8 | 1029 | 2020-12-07 13:18:07 |
| 9 | 1029 | 2020-12-07 13:18:07 |
| 10 | 378 | 2020-12-07 13:19:10 |
| 11 | 378 | 2020-12-07 13:19:10 |

This table grows over time and will persist every time a user is seen. So one user_id can occurs many times per day. Now I'm looking for a SQL query to give me this result:

| week | one-time | two-times | more-than-two-times |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 22 | 4 | 12 |
| 41 | 34 | 12 | 31 |
| 42 | ... | ... | ... |

A user should count one-time per day and column separated how often per week. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

this seems a valid result:

```sql
select
    t.yyyyww,
    SUM(t.num_days = 1) as cnt_1,
    SUM(t.num_days = 2) as cnt_2,
    SUM(t.num_days > 2) as cnt_3plus
from
    (
    select
        WEEKOFYEAR(`at`) as yyyyww, user_id, COUNT(distinct DATE(`at`)) as num_days
    from
        user_seen
    group by
        yyyyww, user_id ) t
group by
    t.yyyyww
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ...and seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of days per week ("a user should count one-time per day").  For this, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select yyyyww, 
       sum(num_days = 1) as cnt_1,
       sum(num_days = 2) as cnt_2,
       sum(num_days > 2) as cnt_3plus
from (select yearweek(at) as yyyyww, user_id,
             count(distinct date(at)) as num_days
      from t
      group by yyyyww, user_id
     ) t
group by yyyyww
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to count the occurences of the same user per week. One option uses two levels of aggregation

```
select wk, 
    sum(cnt = 1) as cnt_1, -- count of users that appeared just once this week
    sum(cnt = 2) as cnt_2,
    sum(cnt = 3) as cnt_3, 
    sum(cnt > 3) cnt_more  -- count of users that appeared more than three times this week
from (
    select yearweek(at) as wk, user_id, count(*) cnt
    from mytable
    group by wk, user_id
) t
group by wk
```

Comment: this response an not valid result  for my usecase, a vary similary query is given by @gorden-linof and this works like a charm.